# How to configure a Jinja configuration file to include service checks based on generic values?

Tags: jinja2, ansible

The ansible in my company is configured to build Nagios templates for some services.

For example:

```
      define service {
            use                     rabbit-critical-service         ; Name of service template to use
            service_description     RabbitMQ {{ queue_name }} queue size
            check_command                   check_graphite_data!1000!15000!rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_messages.{{ queue_name }}.value
            host_name               {{ rabbitmq_server }}
            notifications_enabled   1
            servicegroups           rabbitmq
    }
```

The template builds the check automatically with the same threshold values for all queues. Queue names are configured in a different file under `ansible_playbooks/roles/nagios/defaults/main.yml` and are generated automatically using Jinja.

I've been given the task to make it possible to edit in a somewhat easy way the configuration to include different threshold for some specific checks but I'm having a hard time understanding how to do it.

I thought about something like that:
Adding to the service_check template something like that:

```
{% if queue_size_specific_vars is not defined %}
create the check using the current configuration...
{% else %}
create the check using the specific configuration which will be found in the `default/main.yml` file in the newly created generic value "queue_size_specific_vars" which is supposed to include two values, one for warning value and one for critical value.
{% endif %}
```

My questions are:

> 1. How do I achieve my goal (while taking into consideration two values instead of one)?
> 2. I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve my goal, do you know a better way to do so?

Edit #1:

It seems like I didn't explain myself properly, let me show you a larger portion of the template:

```
{% for queue_name in queues %}
define service {
        use                     rabbit-critical-service         ; Name of service template to use
        service_description     RabbitMQ {{ queue_name }} queue active consumers
        check_command                   check_graphite_data!0.9!0.9!rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_consumers.{{ queue_name }}!reverse
        host_name               {{ rabbitmq_server }}
        notifications_enabled   1
        servicegroups           rabbitmq
        max_check_attempts      4
}

{% if vars_production is not defined %}
define service {
        use                     generic-service
        service_description     RabbitMQ {{ queue_name }} queue read/write ratio
        check_command                   check_graphite!'http://{{ graphite_server }}:{{ graphite_port }}/render/?from=-10minutes&target=scale(divideSeries(offset(prod-rabbit-1.rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_messages.{{queue_name}}.value,1),offset(derivative(sumSeries(prod-rabbit-1.rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_deliver_get.{{queue_name}})),1)),100)&rawData'!1500!2000!avg
        host_name               {{ rabbitmq_server }}
        notifications_enabled   1
        servicegroups           rabbitmq
        max_check_attempts      4
}
{% endif %}
define service {
        use                     rabbit-critical-service         ; Name of service template to use
        service_description     RabbitMQ {{ queue_name }} queue size
        check_command                   check_graphite_data!1000!15000!rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_messages.{{ queue_name }}.value
        host_name               {{ rabbitmq_server }}
        notifications_enabled   1
        servicegroups           rabbitmq
}

{% endfor %}
```

It means that the change I should implement should be in the level of the queue rather than in the hostname, because ansible "knows" only hosts and doesn't "know" queues.

We need the option to set "RabbitMQ {{ queue_name }} queue size" per queue, and have all the rest with the default.
the change I'm expected to do should take place in the template file itself.

Example:

```
{% if special_queue_exists %}
do ....
{% else %}
create it in the normal method
{% endif %}
```

Edit #2:

My manager wants me to do it in a way which resembles this:
I already have the file which includes all the queues, let's call this file "queues_file".
And he wants me to create another file which will include a list of specific check values (warn and critical), let's call this file "specific_values".

And then do something like this:

```
queues_with_specific_metrics:
  - entities:
    - warn: "1000"
    - crit: "20000"
```

And then to check if the queue i'm running on (from the for loop) has specific configuration within the "specific_values" file and if so, then the settings from the "specific_values" file should override the default ones.
Then, I can do something like this:

```
{{ queues_with_specific_metrics.queue.warn | default(1000) }}
```

I'm newbie in Ansible and Jinja and that's why i'm not so understandable, sorry about that.

**Edit #3:**
I've edited the configurations as you proposed, but I'm not sure how to write the if statement...

The defaults/main.yml includes a list of all queue names.

I've opened a new file which is called `spec_params.yml` and resides in the default folder as the `main.yml` file.

The `spec_params.yml` file:

```
nagios_specific_queue_params:
  queue1: {}
  entities:
    warn: 2000
    crit: 20000
```

And the relevant portion of `rabbitmq.cfg.j2`:

```
{% if queue_name in nagios_specific_queue_params %}
define service {
        use                     rabbit-critical-service         ; Name of service template to use
        service_description     RabbitMQ {{ queue_name }} queue size
        check_command           check_graphite_data!{{ queues[queue_name] ['warn'] |default(1000) }}!{{ queues[queue_name] ['crit'] | default(15000) }}!rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_messages.{{ queue_name }}.value
        host_name               {{ rabbitmq_server }}
        notifications_enabled   1
        servicegroups           rabbitmq
}
{% else %}
define service {
        use                     rabbit-critical-service         ; Name of service template to use
        service_description     RabbitMQ {{ queue_name }} queue size
        check_command                   check_graphite_data!1000!15000!rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_messages.{{ queue_name }}.value
        host_name               {{ rabbitmq_server }}
        notifications_enabled   1
        servicegroups           rabbitmq
}
{% endif %}
```

When I run the playbook I get the following error:

```
fatal: [monitoring] => {'msg': "TypeError: argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable", 'failed': True}
fatal: [monitoring] => {'msg': 'One or more items failed.', 'failed': True, 'changed': False, 'results'
```

Any idea why it fails?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Why are you doing "if special_queue_exists"? I think an example of what should be different or what should happen when this "different" queue exists would be useful.

Comment: Please check edit #2, thanks again!

Comment: You can do exactly what you said, but try with `queues_with_specific_metrics[queue]['warn'] | default(1000)` ( Supposing "queue" is the queue name you get from the loop ). This should also work if you haven't defined "queue" in queue_with_specific_metrics

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer with an explanation? that would be great!

Comment: Updated the answer with the elaboration @Itai

Comment: This could be a way of solving it. But using a different file and a different variable name, you would have to use `nagios_specific_queue_params[queue_name]['warn']` instead of `queues[queue_name]['warn']`. Also, if those vars are defaults put them in the same `main.yml` file, if they are not supposed to be defaults, put them somewhere else ( group_vars, host_vars )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the steps I did in order to complete the task:

In `nagios/defaults/main.yml`, I've added:

```
nagios_queue_size_default_values:
  warn: 1000
  crit: 15000
nagios_queue_size_override_values:
  entities_prod_whatever_2:
    warn: 600
    crit: 900
```

Then, in `rabbitmq.cfg.j2`, I've changed the check command to this one:

```
check_command     check_graphite_data!{{ nagios_queue_size_override_values.get(queue_name, nagios_queue_size_default_values).warn }}!{{ nagios_queue_size_override_values.get(queue_name, nagios_queue_size_default_values).crit }}!rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_messages.{{ queue_name }}.value
```

Running the playbook now creates the template as required.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in roles//defaults/ can be overridden by any upper level variable ( ones in /vars, group_vars, host_vars and inventory vars ).

So if you define a variable `queue_size`, in defaults you can then overwrite it in a group/host_vars file.

```
# file: roles/nagios/deaults/main.yml
queue_size: "1000!15000"

# file: host_vars/host1.yml
queue_size: "2000!25000"

# file: host_vars/host2.yml
queue_size: "1000!5000"

# file: roles/nagios/templates/check.j2
      define service {
            use                     rabbit-critical-service         ; Name of service template to use
            service_description     RabbitMQ {{ queue_name }} queue size
            check_command                   check_graphite_data!{{ queue_size }}!rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_messages.{{ queue_name }}.value
            host_name               {{ rabbitmq_server }}
            notifications_enabled   1
            servicegroups           rabbitmq
    }
```

This should answer both your questions. You could also specify a `queue_size_min` and `queue_size_max` if you want to have a cleaner vars file.

Edit:
To better explain what I meant in the comment:

You have two ways ( That I can think of )to solve this:

First: use a separate file, with values for non-default queues. This might be cleaner, but you will have to keep all the queues present in the original var file:

```
# file vars/original_file.yml
queues: 
  - queue1
  - entities

# file vars/specific.yml
queue_with_specific_metrics:
    queue1: {}
    entities:
       warn: 1000
       crit: 15000
```

Second: Edit the original file to include the specific values, when needed

```
queues:
   queue1: {}
   entities:
        warn: 1000
        crit: 2000
```

In either case you would then change the template to take the value or assign default:

```
# case 1
check_command check_graphite_data!{{ queue_with_specific_metrics[queue_name]['warn'] | default(1000) }}!{{ queue_with_specific_metrics[queue_name]['crit'] | default(800) }}!rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_messages.{{ queue_name }}.value}

check_command check_graphite_data!{{ queues[queue_name]['warn'] | default(1000) }}!{{ queues[queue_name]['crit'] | default(800) }}!rabbitmq._.rabbitmq_messages.{{ queue_name }}.value}
```

Comment: There's that loop which goes through all the queues... do I still have to write down each queue name as you shown? I'd like it to be generic...

Comment: queue_name is still the variable generated in the for loop `{% for queue_name in queues %}`

Comment: In your answer, under "second:" the queue1: {} should be the name of the queue from the for loop but it's a dict, so isn't that a problem? a dict consists of static values and queue1 should be each queue from the for loop

Comment: I didn't get the "a dict consists of static values and queue1 should be each queue from the for loop". Anyway, yes `queue1` is a dict, so is entities. When doing `{% for queue_name in queues %}` queue_name will be the dict key ( as you would in python ), and that's why you have to do `queues[queue_name]`

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, please check Edit #3.